# Remove tools.php page from WordPress admin

Tags: wordpress, admin

## Background

The WordPress admin section (/wp-admin) contains a menu item named tools (between users and settings). It has an obtrusive sub-item named "Available Tools" which is a page that contains a feature named "Press This".

```
/wp-admin/tools.php
```

## My question

How do I remove this page from the tools section?

## What I've tried

I've tried a function to remove menu item:

```
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
function my_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_menu_page('press-this.php');
    //remove_menu_page('tools.php');
}
```

If I remove tools.php, the entire tools section is removed rather than just the "Available Tools" section.

I've also tried deleting the press-this.php from the directory.

Neither approaches have been to any avail.

I cannot find a solution **anywhere** online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this way uses WP functions:
tested and work

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_tools' );
function remove_tools() {
    remove_submenu_page('tools.php', 'tools.php');
}
```

Comment: Implemented and understood, thanks. @soju Thanks for the objectivity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `admin_menu` hook to modify `$submenu` global var :

```
add_action('admin_menu','modify_menu');

function modify_menu()
{
  global $submenu;
  unset($submenu['tools.php'][5]);
}
```

EDIT : as janw said in his answer, you should instead use [remove_submenu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. I cannot find similar examples online nor in the WordPress codex (I've search using multiple terminologies). Where can I learn more about the example you provided? I want to learn about the global $submenu variable and the significance of the number 5 in the unset function. A link from anyone in the know would suffice.

Comment: The number 5 is probably the weight of the item menu. My google search for this question : "wordpress remove sub level admin menu", first result : http://erisds.co.uk/wordpress/spotlight-wordpress-admin-menu-remove-add-new-pages-or-posts-link

Comment: The link is useful as is your keyword search. My original keywords were "(remove OR delete OR disable) AND (tools.php OR Press This OR Press It OR Available Tools)".

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It hides the entire Tools menu if there's no other tools available to the user.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_tools_admin_menu');
    function remove_tools_admin_menu() {
        global $submenu;
        unset($submenu['tools.php'][5]);
        if(count($submenu['tools.php']) == 0) {
            remove_menu_page('tools.php');
        }
}
```

Comment: I think 'admin_menu' is a more appropriate action to use than 'admin_init', but otherwise this works well, thanks.